# Algorithms - Extreme specifics about Conways Game of Life

Tags: algorithm, conways-game-of-life

My query is really hard to describe so I will try to explain it as succinctly as possible.

In Conway's Game of Life, let's say I had a map like so:

```
_   _   _   _   _
_   _   _   _   _
U   _   R   Y   _
_   T   _   X   _
_   Z   _   C   _
```

Instead of looping over every single cell, including the dead ones that cannot possibly become relevant, let's say I put every living cell in generation 0 inside a `LinkedList`. Upon each generation update, I would iterate through the entire `LinkedList` and perform the rules that Conway's Game of Life states on each of them. This way I avoid having to iterate over large spans of dead cells for no reason.

One of the rules states `a dead cell with 3 living neighbors becomes living`. Since I'm iterating only though *living* cells in my algorithm, the **only** way I could look at dead cells is by looking at the neighbors of the living cells in my `LinkedList`. I would have to, for every item in my `LinkedList`, loop through all neighboring cells to that cell, and for each neighboring cell I would have to look around that cell, count if it has three neighbors, then set it to `alive` and then add it as a living cell inside the `LinkedList`.

**My Question:**

Obviously my `LinkedList` would quickly get disorganized and would **not** be in a top left -> bottom right order anymore. In the figure I provided above for example, the first cell in my `linkedList` might be `C`, the second might be `R`, the third might be `T`. As new cells are born I would add them to my `LinkedList` and iterate through them in the next generation in whatever order they were added in.

**Is this legal** by the game's rules, or do I need to iterate through the entire 2D array from the top left corner to the bottom right? The rules are incredibly ambiguous.

> Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
>
> Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
>
> Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by over-population.
>
> Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

Do I need to loop through the entire 2D array, do rule:

> Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.

then loop through the entire 2D array again and do rule:

> Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.

Does it even matter in the end? I've read so many posts and no one ever seems to mention this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: The rules impose no order of evaluation. What they do require is double buffering. The current generation is in one buffer, and you build the next generation into a different buffer. Note that although your algorithm will be efficient when there only a few live cells, it becomes incredibly inefficient when a large percentage of the cells are live.

Comment: If you work from top to bottom you only need one row as a buffer (not the hole field).

Comment: @MrSmith42 - As long as you traverse in some linear fashion, I think it's fine and you'll only need to buffer the previous row. Cool idea!

Comment: This seems like a mostly meaningless optimization. I just don't see how scanning empty cells takes up a significant portion of the processing time, especially when you add in the overhead of maintaining your linked list of live cells, and then having to somehow identify the dead cells that will come to life. By the time you're done with your "optimization," the code is more complex and slower than the simple code that scans the entire matrix.

Comment: @JimMischel I think it's a give and take. For example if you had an area of 5000 cells by 5000 cells with a population of 4, my method would only need to loop over 4 cells instead of 5000 squared. Of course as the population gets higher, it's questionable to know if it would save any time at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Conway's game of life, the entire matrix should be looped over only once: all changes are done simultaneously.

This, in effect, would cause the need for two matrices: the old state and the new one. For each cell in the old state, you compute a live neighbor count. Then, if the cell was alive and has 2 or 3 neighbors, it lives on in the new matrix. If the cell was not alive and has 3 neighbors, it spawns. Otherwise, it dies.

The issue with the linked list would be finding neighbor counts. Spawning the next generation would be `O(n^2)` on the number of live cells since the entire list would have to be searched to compute neighbors. Also, you will have to check every neighbor of the cell in the linked list since they spawn.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without two matrices? Or is the entire phenomena of this Game of Life based on completely separating one generation from another? My general thought process is accurate though right? Since in this game, thing only happen around living cells. If a dead cell is around 8 other dead cells, it's a waste to go and loop over him.

Comment: The way to do it without two matrices would be (if you can have objects), to store the previous neighbor count as well. Changes in the matrix happen all at once, so each cell changes as if it were the "first" to change.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-create your linked list every single move. The Conway's Game of Life is processed by turns, where all dead cells that would become living don't count as living at the current turn, and all living cells that would die don't count as dead at the current turn. So, with `LinkedList` approach, you hold two lists (I'd say hash tables instead, because you need a quick function to check if an object is already in the list), one represents current set of living cells, the other represents the collected set of cells that would be alive the next turn. Then, you iterate through the first set of cells, grab the current cell's adjacent ones, stuff them into the next turn's list with "neighbors" equal to 1, and increase that value per living cell processed. Also the current living cell should be added to the set with "living" flag set and neighbors of 0. A pseudocode:

```
ArrayCollection.<Cell> existing; // currently alive cells
ArrayCollection.<Cell> next; // next turn
void processTurn() {
    next.clear();
    for each (Cell cell in existing) {
        Cell nextTC=next.getByParameters(cell); // check presence by X and Y
        if (nextTC) nextTC.alive=true; else   
            next.addNewCell(cell.x,cell.y,0,true); // add a new element
            // 0 is current neighbors, true is alive flag
        for each (Cell neigh in cell.neighbors) {
            nextTC=next.getByParameters(neigh);
            if (nextTC) nextTC.neighbors++; else   
                next.addNewCell(cell.x,cell.y,1,false); // add a new element
                // added a dead cell with 1 neighbor - currently processed alive cell
        }
    }
    for each (cell in next) {
        if (!cell.alive && (cell.neighbors==3)) cell.alive=true; else
        if (cell.alive && ((cell.neighbors==2) || (cell.neighbors==3))) ; // no change
        else next.remove(cell); // dead cell that either was alive or failed to become alive
    }
    swap(current,next);
}
```

Comment: Wow yeah... this definitely got a lot more complicated than I originally thought. I thought you just keep the same matrix updated and somehow loop through it making changes and then re-printing it. This kind of changes everything.